# how resolve unable to resolve "api.twitter.com" no address associate with hostname

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, fatal-error

When I try to share a post on Twitter I obtain this error
My Twitter class where I utilize twitter4j for library  is:

```
public class TwitterActivity extends Activity {

    private Twitter twitter;

    private RequestToken requestToken = null;
    public static final String PREFS = "MyPrefsFile";
    final public static String CALLBACK_URL = "app://casa";
    private SharedPreferences shared;
    private RequestToken re;
    private int it = 0;
    private String frase = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter);

        it = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
        frase = getIntent().getExtras().getString("frase");
        shared = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        new updateTwitterStatus().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent data) {
        super.onNewIntent(data);
        dealWithTwitterResponse(data);

    }

    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Intent i = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey("V***********")
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(
                            "****************");

            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            twitter = tf.getInstance();

            try {
// the next line throws the error
                requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);
                Log.i("bauu", "miao");

                String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                return authUrl;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void dealWithTwitterResponse(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Sonod entro", "vau");
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri == null) {
            Log.i("è null", "null");
        }
        Log.i("callback funziona", "ciao");
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {
            final String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
            final String oauthToken = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Log.i("SOno dentro il run", "asd");
                        AccessToken at = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                requestToken, verifier);

                        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(at);
                        twitter.updateStatus("CHI VUOLE ESSERE SCIENZIATO?? Punteggio: "
                                + it
                                + " "
                                + frase
                                + " "
                                + "www.scienze-naturali.com");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.punteggio, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and xml FIle is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.applicazionescienza"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.MenuPrincipale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Informazioni"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_informazioni" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Regolamento"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_regolamento" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Gioca"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gioca" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Livello"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_livello" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.Punteggio"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_punteggio" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.TwitterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_twitter"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="casa"
                    android:scheme="app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.applicazionescienza.FacebookActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I sign in the code the line where the error is throwed
Anyone can help me?

Comment: What device/ emulator are you using? try hitting any other url from the application and check if this error persists.

Comment: @Naresh R I'm using Galaxy S3...On emulatore It works but in galasyS3 no!

Comment: Check the network connectivity in your S3. If you use some proxy for WiFi or something check if you bypass them.

Comment: @Naresh R but Why in Galaxy S2 it works and in Galaxy S3 it doesn't work and they have both android 4.1.2?

Comment: Android version doesn't matter. It doesn't matter on the device as well. All it matters is whether that is connected to internet in your device or not. If connected, is twitter blocked by your proxy, if you have one? But since The same application runs fine on other devices, its not the fault on your app. That's for sure.

Comment: Thanks, I got this exception because of my device didn't connected with internet.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on a tablet. I seemed to be connected to the Internet on the device but there was actually a connection problem. To fix the error I just had to disable and reenable wifi on the device.

Answer (score 0):

On the same device, try going to https://api.twitter.com in a browser. If it connects, then it's most likely to be an issue with the app /twitter4j than the wi-fi.